# reactgridlayout: Warning: Failed prop type: Duplicate child key "0" found

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I am trying to do is have a new button to create only chart elements. However, opening console will display this error `Warning: Failed prop type: Duplicate child key "0" found!`

Below is my code

```
...

class MinMaxLayout extends React.PureComponent {
  static defaultProps = {
    items: 5,
    charts: 2,
    rowHeight: 30,
    cols: 12
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(function (i, key, list) {
        return {
          i: i.toString(),
          x: i * 2,
          y: 0,
          w: 2,
          h: 2,
          add: i === list.length - 1
        };
      }),

      charts: [0, 1].map(function (i, key, list) {
        return {
          i: i.toString(),
          x: i * 2,
          y: 0,
          w: 2,
          h: 2,
          add: i === list.length - 1
        };
      }),
      newCounter: 0,
      chartCounter: 0
    };

    this.onAddItem = this.onAddItem.bind(this);
    this.onChartItem = this.onChartItem.bind(this);
    this.onBreakpointChange = this.onBreakpointChange.bind(this);
  }

  createElement(el) {
    const removeStyle = {
      position: "absolute",
      right: "2px",
      top: 0,
      cursor: "pointer"
    };
    const i = el.add ? "+" : el.i;
    return (
      <div key={i} data-grid={el}>
        {/* <span className="text">{i}</span> */}
        <span
          className="remove"
          style={removeStyle}
          onClick={this.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)}
        >
          x
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  createChart(el) {
    const removeStyle = {
      position: "absolute",
      right: "2px",
      top: 0,
      cursor: "pointer"
    };
    const i = el.add ? "+" : el.i;
    return (
      <div key={i} data-grid={el}>
        <span
          className="remove"
          style={removeStyle}
          onClick={this.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)}
        >
          x
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onAddItem() {
    /*eslint no-console: 0*/
    console.log("adding", "n" + this.state.newCounter);
    this.setState({
      // Add a new item. It must have a unique key!
      items: this.state.items.concat({
        i: "n" + this.state.newCounter,
        x: (this.state.items.length * 2) % (this.state.cols || 12),
        y: Infinity, // puts it at the bottom
        w: 2,
        h: 2
      }),
      // Increment the counter to ensure key is always unique.
      newCounter: this.state.newCounter + 1
    });
  }

  onChartItem() {
    /*eslint no-console: 0*/
    console.log("adding chart", "n" + this.state.chartCounter);
    this.setState({
      // Add a new item. It must have a unique key!
      charts: this.state.charts.concat({
        i: "n" + this.state.chartCounter,
        x: (this.state.charts.length * 2) % (this.state.cols || 12),
        y: Infinity, // puts it at the bottom
        w: 8,
        h: 6
      }),
      // Increment the counter to ensure key is always unique.
      chartCounter: this.state.chartCounter + 1
    });
  }

  // We're using the cols coming back from this to calculate where to add new items.
  onBreakpointChange(breakpoint, cols) {
    this.setState({
      breakpoint: breakpoint,
      cols: cols
    });
  }

  onRemoveItem(i) {
    console.log("removing", i);
    this.setState({ items: _.reject(this.state.items, { i: i }) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="DetailLocationContainer">
        <button onClick={this.onAddItem}>Add Item</button>
        <button onClick={this.onChartItem}>Add Chart</button>
        <ReactGridLayout
          onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange}
          {...this.props}
        >
          {_.map(this.state.items, (el) => this.createElement(el))}
          {_.map(this.state.charts, (el) => this.createChart(el))}
        </ReactGridLayout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

...
```

**Expected result:** no error message

**Actual result:** Warning: Failed prop type: Duplicate child key "0" found

Click this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/warning-failed-prop-type-duplicate-child-key-0-found-81ttz?file=/src/index.js:0-4178) for my codesandbox. will appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You are rendering two sets of data into a component, using array indices as keys, and so you've duplicate keys among the ***entire*** set of siblings.

## Solution

You shouldn't use array indices as React keys as they don't generally provide uniqueness, as you've found out, and they aren't intrinsic to the array elements, generally.

I suggest adding a GUID property to each object you create, and use this `id` property as the React key.

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

...

this.state = {
  items: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(function (i, key, list) {
    return {
      id: uuidV4(), // <-- id property
      ....
    };
  }),
  charts: [0, 1].map(function (i, key, list) {
    return {
      id: uuidV4(), // <-- id property
      ....
    };
  }),
  ....
};

...

<div key={el.id} data-grid={el}> // <-- el.id is React key
  ...
</div>
```

[image: Edit reactgridlayout-warning-failed-prop-type-duplicate-child-key-0-found]

Full code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import RGL, { WidthProvider } from "react-grid-layout";
import _ from "lodash";
import "./styles.css";
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

const ReactGridLayout = WidthProvider(RGL);

class MinMaxLayout extends React.PureComponent {
  static defaultProps = {
    items: 5,
    charts: 2,
    rowHeight: 30,
    cols: 12
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(function (i, key, list) {
        return {
          id: uuidV4(),
          i: i.toString(),
          x: i * 2,
          y: 0,
          w: 2,
          h: 2,
          add: i === list.length - 1
        };
      }),

      charts: [0, 1].map(function (i, key, list) {
        return {
          id: uuidV4(),
          i: i.toString(),
          x: i * 2,
          y: 0,
          w: 2,
          h: 2,
          add: i === list.length - 1
        };
      }),
      newCounter: 0,
      chartCounter: 0
    };

    this.onAddItem = this.onAddItem.bind(this);
    this.onChartItem = this.onChartItem.bind(this);
    this.onBreakpointChange = this.onBreakpointChange.bind(this);
  }

  createElement(el) {
    const removeStyle = {
      position: "absolute",
      right: "2px",
      top: 0,
      cursor: "pointer"
    };
    const i = el.add ? "+" : el.i;
    return (
      <div key={el.id} data-grid={el}>
        {/* <span className="text">{i}</span> */}
        <span
          className="remove"
          style={removeStyle}
          onClick={this.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)}
        >
          x
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  createChart(el) {
    const removeStyle = {
      position: "absolute",
      right: "2px",
      top: 0,
      cursor: "pointer"
    };
    const i = el.add ? "+" : el.i;
    return (
      <div key={el.id} data-grid={el}>
        <span
          className="remove"
          style={removeStyle}
          onClick={this.onRemoveItem.bind(this, i)}
        >
          x
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onAddItem() {
    /*eslint no-console: 0*/
    console.log("adding", "n" + this.state.newCounter);
    this.setState({
      // Add a new item. It must have a unique key!
      items: this.state.items.concat({
        id: uuidV4(),
        i: "n" + this.state.newCounter,
        x: (this.state.items.length * 2) % (this.state.cols || 12),
        y: Infinity, // puts it at the bottom
        w: 2,
        h: 2
      }),
      // Increment the counter to ensure key is always unique.
      newCounter: this.state.newCounter + 1
    });
  }

  onChartItem() {
    /*eslint no-console: 0*/
    console.log("adding chart", "n" + this.state.chartCounter);
    this.setState({
      // Add a new item. It must have a unique key!
      charts: this.state.charts.concat({
        id: uuidV4(),
        i: "n" + this.state.chartCounter,
        x: (this.state.charts.length * 2) % (this.state.cols || 12),
        y: Infinity, // puts it at the bottom
        w: 8,
        h: 6
      }),
      // Increment the counter to ensure key is always unique.
      chartCounter: this.state.chartCounter + 1
    });
  }

  // We're using the cols coming back from this to calculate where to add new items.
  onBreakpointChange(breakpoint, cols) {
    this.setState({
      breakpoint: breakpoint,
      cols: cols
    });
  }

  onLayoutChange(layout) {
    this.props.onLayoutChange(layout);
    this.setState({ layout: layout });
  }

  onRemoveItem(i) {
    console.log("removing", i);
    this.setState({ items: _.reject(this.state.items, { i: i }) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="DetailLocationContainer">
        <button onClick={this.onAddItem}>Add Item</button>
        <button onClick={this.onChartItem}>Add Chart</button>
        <ReactGridLayout
          onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange}
          {...this.props}
        >
          {_.map(this.state.items, (el) => this.createElement(el))}
          {_.map(this.state.charts, (el) => this.createChart(el))}
        </ReactGridLayout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = MinMaxLayout;

if (require.main === module) {
  require("../test-hook.jsx")(module.exports);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MinMaxLayout />, rootElement);
```